# Show the arrangement stack of a page or document

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-writer

Right-clicking an image (or -for the lack of better word- other "object") on a page

[image: bring to front]

in arrange menu, options such as "bring to front" is shown.

I suppose this is analogue to the z-axis or z-order of things.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to **list the order** of these "objects" on a page or on the document?

---

It would look something like:

[image: listofthings-originalwork]

source: (1) screenshot (2) original work by me

(Alternatively, how hard would be to do this in a clear straightforward way with the source inside the zipped xml that is ooxml?)

While this question applies to Libreoffice Writer 5 or Apache OpenOffice Writer 4, I am interested in other word processor products too *as an extension* (as in willing to try them instead) in case this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/cd05/OpenDocument-v1.2-cd05-part1.html#attribute-draw_z-index:

> The draw:z-index attribute defines a rendering order for shapes in a document instance. Shapes are rendered in the order in which they appear in the document in the absence of this attribute.

Unzipping the ODT file and opening content.xml shows lines like the following (look at the end especially):

```
<draw:frame draw:style-name="fr1" draw:name="Frame2" text:anchor-type="paragraph" svg:x="0.411in" svg:y="0.048in" svg:width="0.7902in" draw:z-index="2">
```

So it is possible to look through the file (I used Chrome browser) and see the z-order.  Or, it should be possible to write a script to parse content.xml and list the object names, sorted by `draw:z-index`.

Or a macro could do it.  From https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Drawings/Ordering:

> If there are many shapes on a page, the shape that has the lowest ZOrder value is drawn first.

But it does not look like LibreOffice provides such an ordered list.